# How do I create a re-useable POST view object in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm creating a sandbox in dotnet core for my website and I'm digging the MVVM benefits and simplicity of Razor Pages over MVC. I realize that Razor Pages are supposed to be more simple, but Razor Pages, View Components or even MVC I can't imagine how to accomplish what I need, and was looking for guidance on best-practices:

I have a page on which I upload some files. There are 3 different types of files I can upload and they all go store the files in different locations with different file types. I want to keep this Single Responsibility principle and have 3 separate pages, allowing me to have 3 Separate Views housing the Upload View Object

How can I create a re-useable View Object, and what would the proper term be, that would allow me to, OnPost, upload Files to my server? Would it be a Partial Page or ViewComponent combined with a receiving WebApi controller? Would it be possible to perform action OnPost in a single location so that I don't build tons of code around it?

Answer (score 0):

View Components encapsulate HTML and logic. If you want to centralise the upload form but separate the processing, a Partial View will be more suitable.

Comment: I'd like to have a single unit centrailzing and separating the upload form and the processing from the main Page/View. My workaround right now looks alright but leaves me with a sense of "but does is this wrong?"

Comment: So I have a partial page that implements an interface IUploadPageModel. Interface contains Properties IList<IFormFile> UploadedFiles and IFileUploadBehavior. To call the partial you pass in the parent model, which is required to implement IUploadPageModel. However, with all of that runaround logic going on, it seems to best leave this as a controller, which I figure could still implement the IUploadPageModel, which should then be renamed IUploadViewModel. Even so however, it still seems a bit of a hackish approach to solve the problem of re-using core logic that can be changed with injection.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer to your question. One thing - partials should not have a PageModel. If it has a PageModel, it should be a ViewComponent. Also, there is nothing wrong with having alternate workflows (runaround logic) in the same class, and selecting one based on the context.